# AndroidアプリでWebviewからhtml5のvideoタグの再生

Tags: android, html5, webview

Androidアプリ上でWebViewを使い、ローカルにあるhtml5のコードを実行していますが、
videoがどうしても再生できません。

html5WebViewというのも使って見ましたが、ダメでした。

どなたか、html5のvideoをWebView上で再生する方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
videoはローカルに保存してあるものです。

Androidのバージョンは4.2以上を想定しています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「再生出来ない」というのは、まったく再生されず「videoタグ内が”真っ黒”」ということですか？ まずは、動画の形式（mp4なのかどうか）を確認し、再生されるべき形式なのであれば、type属性を除くなのどの対応をとってみて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

「PluginStateをONにしていない」ということはないでしょうか？以下のようなコードを書いてPluginをONにして、videoタグが含まれるWebページを表示してみて下さい。

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
} else {
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}
```